# How to get object from Play cache (scala)

Tags: scala, caching, playframework

How to get object from Play cache (scala)

Code to set:

```
play.api.cache.Cache.set("mykey98",  new Product(98), 0)
```

Code to get:

```
val product1: Option[Any]  = play.api.cache.Cache.get("mykey98")
```

I get Option object. How to get actual Product object I stored in first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, I would suggest using `Cache.getAs`, which takes a type parameter. That way you won't be stuck with `Option[Any]`. There are a few ways you can do this. In my example, I'll use `String`, but it will work the same with any other class. My preferred way is by pattern matching:

```
import play.api.cache.Cache

Cache.set("mykey", "cached string", 0)

val myString:String = Cache.getAs[String]("mykey") match {
    case Some(string) => string
    case None => SomeOtherClass.getNewString() // or other code to handle an expired key
}
```

This example is a bit over-simplified for pattern matching, but I think its a nicer method when needing to branch code based on the existence of a key. You could also use `Cache.getOrElse`:

```
val myString:String = Cache.getOrElse[String]("mykey") {
    SomeOtherClass.getNewString()
}
```

In your specific case, replace `String` with `Product`, then change the code to handle what will happen if the key does not exist (such as setting a default key).

Comment: It should be noted that `getOrElse` will in case of missing value store the result value back to cache.